# Linq to Entities Non-Equal Join

Tags: linq, join, iqueryable, entities, iequalitycomparer

I must perform the following SQL command using IQueryable:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable t1 
    INNER JOIN myTable t2 ON t1.time = t2.time + 1 
        OR t1.time = t2.time + 2 
        OR t1.time = t2.time + 3;
```

Linq to Entities does not allow me to use IEqualityComparer, so I'm looking for some way to accomplish this Join.

Must use IQueryable and can not put conditions via Where as myTable has millions of records and implementation would be very slow:

```
qry = qry.Join(...).Where(...);
```

I need

```
qry = qry.Join(...);
```

Is there an alternative like IEqualityComparer for Linq to Entities?

Thank you!
Sorry my bad english!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this works with Lambda-Expression, but you can use Linq to achieve that:

```
var l = from i1 in conn.List1
    from i2 in conn.List2
    where
    (
        i1.time == i2.Time + 1
        || i1.time == i2.Time + 2
        || i1.time == i2.Time + 3
    )
    select new { i1, i2 }
```

Try also following:

```
var l = from i2 in conn.List2.Where(x =>  i1.time == x.Time + 1
                                    || i1.time == x.Time + 2
                                    || i1.time == x.Time + 3)
select new { i1, i2 }
```

Comment: I need to use and not use IQueryable Where. The database has millions of records, if I do Where after the Join takes forever to complete the Join.

Comment: Can you try the second solution?

Answer (score 0):

Linq only supports equi-joins, so you will need to do this through a where clause.

That said, I would not expect a significant performance difference between a compound inner join and using a `where` clause - SQL should create similar (if not equal) plans for the following two queries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable t1 
INNER JOIN myTable t2 ON t1.time = t2.time + 1 
    OR t1.time = t2.time + 2 
    OR t1.time = t2.time + 3;

SELECT * 
FROM myTable t1 ,
myTable t2 
WHERE t1.time = t2.time + 1 
    OR t1.time = t2.time + 2 
    OR t1.time = t2.time + 3;
```